# VB.NET & ASP.NET MVC importing csv file and displaying the data in a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am building a test project to import a `.csv` file, amend certain data and display it in a table view. Looking at examples, I have used view data. The file is being read, but I cannot work out how to display the data in a table view

Controller

```vb
Function Create() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function

<HttpPost()>
Function Create(upload As HttpPostedFileBase) As ActionResult
    Try
        If upload IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim _skiplines As Integer = 3
            Dim _posSortcode As Integer = 0
            Dim _posAccountNumber As Integer = 1
            Dim _posAccountName As Integer = 2
            Dim _posReference As Integer = 4
            Dim _posRTI As Integer = 999
            Dim _posValue As Integer = 3

            'Create Trasnaction Sets
            Dim _licence As String = "217514"
            Dim _paymentdate As String = "01/01/2024"
            Dim _serialnumber As String = "123456"
            Dim _accountid As String = "000006"
            Dim _createdby As String = "Peter"

            Dim _sortcode As String = String.Empty
            Dim _accountNumber As String = String.Empty
            Dim _accountName As String = String.Empty
            Dim _reference As String = String.Empty
            Dim _Rti As String = String.Empty
            Dim _value As String = String.Empty

            Dim LineArray As String()
            Dim Counter As Integer = 0
            Dim ItemCounter As Integer = 0

            Dim TSetList(6) As String

            If upload.ContentLength > 0 Then
                Dim importfile = New ImportFile
                importfile.FileName = upload.FileName


                Using reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(upload.InputStream)
                    If _skiplines > 0 Then
                        For Counter = 1 To _skiplines
                            reader.ReadLine()
                        Next
                    End If

                    Do While Not reader.EndOfStream
                        LineArray = Split(reader.ReadLine, ",")
                        ' Sort Code
                        If Not _posSortcode = 999 Then
                            _sortcode = LineArray(_posSortcode)
                        Else
                            _sortcode = ""
                        End If
                        ' Account Number
                        If Not _posAccountNumber = 999 Then
                            _accountNumber = LineArray(_posAccountNumber)
                        Else
                            _accountNumber = ""
                        End If
                        ' Account Name
                        If Not _posAccountName = 999 Then
                            _accountName = LineArray(_posAccountName)
                        Else
                            _accountName = ""
                        End If
                        ' Reference
                        If Not _posReference = 999 Then
                            _reference = LineArray(_posReference)
                        Else
                            _reference = ""
                        End If
                        ' RTI Code
                        If Not _posRTI = 999 Then
                            _Rti = LineArray(_posRTI)
                        Else
                            _Rti = ""
                        End If
                        ' Value
                        If Not _posValue = 999 Then
                            _value = LineArray(_posValue)
                        Else
                            _value = ""
                        End If

                        TSetList(0) = _sortcode
                        TSetList(1) = _accountNumber
                        TSetList(2) = _accountName
                        TSetList(3) = _reference
                        TSetList(4) = _Rti
                        TSetList(5) = _value

                        ItemCounter = ItemCounter + 1

                    Loop
                    ViewData("transactions") = TSetList
                    reader.Close()
                End Using
                ViewBag.Message = "Completed With " & CStr(ItemCounter)
            End If
        Else
            ViewBag.Message = "No File Found"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ViewBag.Error = ex.Message.ToString
    End Try
    Return View()
End Function
```

View

```html
    @Using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "File", Nothing, FormMethod.Post, New With {.enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
    @<div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Instructor</h4>
        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" id="ImportFile" name="upload" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @ViewBag.Message
    End Using

    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Sort Code")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Account Number")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Account Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Reference")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("RTI")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Value")
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="helpRowBody">
        @Html.Raw(ViewData("transactions"))
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Firstly, you absolutely should not be using ViewData for that. It's not that it won't work but it is conceptually wrong. Different people will have slightly different opinions about how to use ViewData but pretty much everyone would agree that the data that is the primary focus of the view should be passed to that view as the model.

Comment: As for your question, you need a loop in the view. You would use a For Each loop over your list and write one row of data per iteration. I'm sure there are plenty of examples of this. BTW, if you pass the data via the model, it will be strongly typed, so there will be no need to cast to access the data.